# ParseError when opening a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looping through a folder and opening hundrerds of CSV files (with no column names), concatenating them in a single pandas Dataframe, but some of these CSV files are filled with NaN values, written as "N/A", this somehow makes pandas raise the error:

`ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 18 and found 17`

This even happens if I specify which columns I want to use when reading the file

```
pd.read_csv(file, header=None, usecols=[3,5,11,14], sep=';')
```

And even if I check the file manually, I can see that there are no values in an extra column.
Is there a way of getting around this?

Edit:  I figured that when the loop reaches a faulty CSV file, if I open said file with MS Excel and delete the last column, even if that column has only blank cells, pandas will then manage to read it, and the loop continues until it reaches another faulty CSV...

Comment: Given that the sep is `;` the error makes me think there is a stray `;` in one of the columns.

Comment: also maybe catch the exception / drop into the debugger and find which file and line the error is thrown in?

Comment: there are no stray `;`, I forgot to say something relevant, the error happens when the loop reaches a file that contains cells with `N/A`, if I manually delete the rows with `N/A`, then pandas manage to read the csv, but since I have hundreds of files, manually deleting the rows would be a nightmare I would like to avoid, since most of them have at least 1 row with NaN values

Comment: hmm, the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) tell that by default the `na_values` should include that... maybe be a bug in pandas? which pandas version? maybe also try to narrow it down further with manually setting `na_value=['NaN', 'N/A']` and `error_bad_lines=False`... also try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise i'm not sure anyone here can help...

Comment: those settings didnt work, unfortunately, but I found out that by opening the CSV with MS Excel, and deleting the last column, even tho there is no value in a single cell of that column, will enable pandas to read the file. The loop continues and the same error is raised when it reaches another faulty file. I've come to the conclusion that it has nothing to do with the presence of NaN values